# Find the maximum profit of two variables

Tags: calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

It costs a company $\$2$ per unit to make its product. If $A$ dollars are spent per month on advertising, then the number of units per month that will be sold is given by
$$
x=30(1-e^{-0.001A})(22-p)
$$
where $p$ is the selling price. Find the values of $A$ and $p$ that will maximize the firm's net monthly profit and calculate the value of this maximum profit.

it is known that the profit is given by
$$
U= (px)-(2x+A)
$$
and by partially deriving and setting to zero, i have

$\frac{\partial U}{\partial p}=30(1-e^{-0.001A})(-2)(p-12)=0$, then $A=0$ and $p=12$.

$\frac{\partial U}{\partial A}=0.03(22−p)(p−2)e^{-0.001A}-1=0$, then $p=2$ and $p=22$, but $A$ is not defined.

Also, there must always be an objective function, and a function to replace, I have no idea which is the function to replace. I really appreciate the help

Comment: In the second equation, when you substitute $p=2$ or $p=22$, you get $-1=0$.

Comment: it's true, in my mind I was omitting the -1, thanks! but by the quadratic formula I have that $p = 36.8$. And I still have problems with the $A$, is that if it is advertising it should not give zero

Answer (score 1):

The function is not differentiable when $A=0$, since you can't spend negative dollars on advertising.  So, your analysis of the first equation gives $p=12$.  Now substitute $p=12$ in the second equation, and solve for $A$.  Both conditions must be satisfied at a critical point, so you can the result from the first equation to the second.

You still have to consider what happens when $A=0$, but the original equation shows that if $A=0$, then $x=0$ and this is not the maximum, I hope.

Perhaps I should add that I didn't check the differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

$$0.03(22−p)(p−2)e^{−0.001A} − 1 = 0$$
$$0.03(22−p)(p−2)e^{−0.001A} = 1, \text{where p = 12}$$
$$3 e^{−0.001A} = 1$$
$$A = 1000 * \log3$$